# Reading the android navigation route

Tags: android, navigation

For an application I'm researching I need to either read the android navigation route the user is currently following, or receive an intent when the user starts navigating.

The only information regarding to android and the navigation api is how to start the navigation with an intent. This is *not* what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is at best undocumented and hopefully is impossible, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Why is this so bad? With the right permissions, this should be possible. Accessing text messages is just as bad, as well as accessing dialer data.

Comment: @EtHeO: "With the right permissions, this should be possible" -- the Google Navigation app has no documented and supported API, let alone documented and supported custom permissions.

Comment: the "should" was meant as "I see no reason why this is such a bad thing", not as a "I'm pretty sure it exists".

Comment: @EtHeO: *If* there were a documented and supported API for Google Navigation and *if* it had a custom "let people spy on me" permission that apps could hold, I might agree with you. Neither of those "if" statements are true. Based on your research on "how to start the navigation with an intent", you should already have known that there is no documented and supported API, which would therefore have precluded any documented and supported custom permission.